Recommendation Letter sent from an unofficial email of the director of a start-up
I work for a start-up. Due to budget constraints, employees don't have company domain specific emails yet, we just have one general domain email ID for clients to contact the company. I need to get a recommendation letter for my application to graduate schools in the US, mainly for an MS in Engineering Management. Will my application be rejected if the director of the company sends in the LoR from their personal email? Or can I use the one general domain specific email ID the company has to send in the LoR?

Is there a portal for uploading documents? Or are they emailed?

No need to worry. There will either be a portal to upload the letter, or the person on the other side of the email address to which the email is sent will accept it as is. While it is usual for people in academia in the US to send these letters from the official email address at their home institution, it is quite common for people in other countries to use their personal email address for this (and for other work-related emails). We in the US know this, and accept things this way.
